# Is it possible to upgrade the barbarian's stances?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

The four original classes in Dungeon Defenders all have some type of stationary defence (towers, traps and auras). When levelling up, you can choose to improve defence health, damage, range and attack rate.

Since the barbarian has stances instead of stationary defences, is it possible to upgrade those in a similar manner? Are the same four attributes (health, damage, range and attack rate) still applicable to stances?

Comment: I should mention that the barbarian is a new class that recently became available as DLC. It was released yesterday (Jan. 31st, 2012) for PC.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  Instead of tower health, damage, area of effect and rate of fire, the barbarian can put points into each stance.

[image: Proof]